# NSlookup and linux Dig

Tags: nslookup, dig

On linux I can list all entries in the DNS table ending with "80" using:

```
dig axfr my.domain | grep 80
```

How do I do that with NSlookup on windows? I have tried starting NSlookup and typing

```
ls my.domain
```

Which gives me the full list. But how do I filter the resultset like using grep on linux?

I have tried:

```
C:\Users\user>nslookup -ls my.domain | find "80"
*** Invalid option: ls
```

but it gives the above error.

Comment: I think it might be better to rephrase your question on how to get grep-like functionality in Windows.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is the `find` command.

```
nslookup -ls my.domain | find "80"
```

Note though that neither `grep 80` nor `find "80"` will only return those entries **ending** in `80`. They will both return entries that **contain** `80`. If you truly only want entries that **end** in `80` it would be better to use `findstr` with the `/e` flag (matches the pattern if at the end of a line) as well as including a leading period (otherwise you might get something like 10.21.37.180).

```
nslookup -ls my.domain | findstr /e ".80"
```

You can also use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which is *"a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows."*

**EDIT**

If `nslookup -ls my.domain` is giving you an error, then you might try

```
 echo ls my.domain | nslookup | find "80"
```

or if you really only want the ones that end in `.80` try

```
 echo ls my.domain | nslookup | findstr /e ".80"
```

Comment: I did try that see edited post on windows 7 but it gives an error. I have bot tried from cmd and from a started instance of nslookup.exe

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 5):

I believe more elegant solution is to use powershell. It's certainly better than using Cygwin on a Windows machine - for one thing it's built-in.

In Bash we write:

```
dig axfr my.domain | grep "80"
```

The equivalent in Powershell would be:

```
nslookup -ls my.domain | where {$_ -match "80"}
```

Or even better to use regex to make sure only lines ending with `80` are going to be matched:

```
nslookup -ls my.domain | where {$_ -match "(80)$"}
```

---

Additionally if you are interested in domain zone transfers, you might find [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/24389/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-complete-zone-file-for-a-domain-without-contacting-its/784721#784721) useful (and here's a [GitHub project](https://github.com/mnmnc/medved)).

Comment: It may be better than Cygwin, but Git Bash, for one, doesn't put all the bloat on your computer. Also, you don't need to install *every single Cygwin package*, just the ones you need.